# Jmeter - how to write specific variable to CSV file to specific row/column

Tags: jmeter

My csv file looks like:

```
TC_name, username, password, excpecedCode
ad_test_master_successful_login,username,Test123!,200
```

What is the easiest way to so i can write to csv to specific row/column, and example to overwrite Test123! with variable fetched from user defined variables?

I know i can read value using JSR223 Pre/post processor with ex:

```
def line10 = new File('C:/Users/test/Desktop/testData/login.csv').readLines().get(1).split(",")[2]
log.warn("csv as-> " + line10);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such concept as "cell" in CSV files, if you're looking for the code which will replace one string with another, you can do something like:

```
def file = new File('test.csv')
def text = file.text.replaceAll('Test123!', vars.get('foo'))
file.text = text
```

If you're looking for a better option you can consider using [GroovyCSV](http://xlson.com/groovycsv/) library (you will need to download it and place in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) followed by JMeter restart) or consider switching to Excel file where you will have full control via [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) library like it's described in [How to Implement Data Driven Testing in your JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-implement-data-driven-testing-in-your-jmeter-test) article